# Django - which create() method to override before saving incoming data as object

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have the following model in my `models.py` file:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='Videos/',
                              blank=True)
    gif = models.FileField(upload_to='Images/',
                              blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created', )
```

Before Django creates an instance of this model, I want to set the `gif` field on the Django site.
So, the data comes to Django from the client site with the field `video` set, and based on the `video` field's content I want to fill the `gif` field.

For that, which `create()` method do I need to override for this task? 
The `create()` method of my `VideoSerializer` class in `serializers.py` :

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        return Video(**validated_data)
```

Or the create() method of my `VideoCreate` class in `views.py`:

```
class VideoCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, )

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Hope someone can help

Comment: In terms of result, it doesn't matter. Both will work. From an architecture point of view, I'd use the `Model`'s `save()` method for this. It's the model that should know how to save itself, check whether or not the `gif` exists and add it if needed.

Comment: How would that look like ? In the django rest framework documentation I could not find the save() method

Comment: The `Model` I said. Look at the django docs for `Model`

Comment: ok. I used it. But now I get the following error I described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60852102/django-trying-to-create-a-gif-from-uploaded-video